# C++: Looping through a map and comparing key

Tags: c++, dictionary

I'm trying to loop through a map in c++ and compare the key to something but it doesn't work, this is my code:

```
map<string, vector> mymap:

for ( auto const& it : mymap ){
    if (it.first == 'e'){
            //do something
    }

}
```

Comment: Please elaborate on "doesn't work." Compilation error? If so, paste its text. Linker error? If so, paste its text. Unexpected runtime behaviour? If so, describe both expected and observed. Etc.

Comment: Why is 'e' in single quotes?

Comment: Firstly, calling the `std::pair` that you get back `it` is a bit confusing. Secondly, you are trying to compare a `std::string` to a `char`. [There is not `operator==` for this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp).

Comment: As an aside, this is a really bad way of using a map.  Consider using `const auto it = mymap.find("e"); if (it != mymap.end()) { /* do something */ }`

Comment: I get an error 'Can't compare structures'

Answer (score 4):

You should use the `find()` Method to search for a value in a map. This way, you don't need to iterate over the map yourself. Example:

```
auto it(mymap.find("e"));

if (it != mymap.end())
{
  // do something
}
```

EDIT: As Angew said, in your code example you are trying to find a string  via a character (`'e'`). Use double quotations in your comparison to compare the correct types (`"e"`).

Comment: True indeed. However, you should also spell out the difference between `'e'` and `"e"`, which is likely the crux of the OP's issue.

Comment: Thanks that seems to work, how do I acces the value of the key? I use     mymap[it]

Comment: I ask it because I want to do add an element to the value, which is an array. But if I want to mymap[it].push_back(something) I get an error saying mymap[it] is not an array

Comment: You can acces the value by using `it->second`. The iterator itself references the values saved in the map and treats them like a `std::pair`. So you can access the value by using second (i.e. `it->second.push_back(yourValue)`). If you want to work with the key, use `it->first`.

Comment: @B.Verbeke You don't want `mymap[it]`, you want `mymap["e"].push_back`.  Note: That will create an empty value if it doesn't already exist.  That may be what you want - in which case, great!

Answer (score 0):

You can use "find" function to get it's availability in container.

```
map<string, vector> mymap:

for ( auto const& it : mymap ){
    if (it.find("e") != it.end()){
            //do something
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

it.first is a string and you are trying to compare it with character literal 'e'. You can compare it with string literal "e" however. Or call find method to find an item with this key without looping at all.